# sorting number via descending order without 0

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to make numbers in descending order but when it reaches 0, the number should turn into 9..

for example, let say `num` is 2, the order should be `2, 1, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3`

```
var num = 2;
$(function() {
        $(".one").html(num);
        $(".two").html((num-1)%9);
        $(".three").html((num-2)%9);
        $(".four").html((num-3)%9);
        $(".five").html((num-4)%9);
        $(".six").html((num-5)%9);
        $(".seven").html((num-6)%9);
        $(".eight").html((num-7)%9);
        $(".nine").html((num-8)%9);
});​
```

But in the code there is 0 and negative numbers, how do i overcome that?

http://jsfiddle.net/yqGV7/

Thank you for your assistance.

Comment: This isn't sorting, it's decrementing, and can be done very easily using a loop with an if statement checking for num being 0.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try this:

```
var num = 3;
$(function() {
    $('span').each(function(i){
        num--;
        if (num == 0) {
           num = 9;
        }
        $(this).text(num)
    })
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/yqGV7/4/)

Answer (score 1):

Not the cleanest code, but will do what you're saying:

```
var num = 2;
num = num + 9;
$(function() {
    $(".one").html(num % 9 || 9);
    $(".two").html((num-1)%9 || 9);
    $(".three").html((num-2)%9 || 9);
    $(".four").html((num-3)%9 || 9);
    $(".five").html((num-4)%9 || 9);
    $(".six").html((num-5)%9 || 9);
    $(".seven").html((num-6)%9 || 9);
    $(".eight").html((num-7)%9 || 9);
    $(".nine").html((num-8)%9 || 9);
});​
```

Answer (score 1):

Cleaner:

```
var num = 2;
$("span").each(function(idx) {
    $(this).text(((num - idx) % 9 + 9) % 9 || 9);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var num = 2;
var max = 9;
$(".one, .two, .three, .four, .five, .six, .seven, .eight, .nine").each(function(i,e){
  if(num>i) { 
    $(e).html(num-i);
  } else { 
    $(e).html(max-(i-num));
  } 
});
```

Here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/yqGV7/6/